# HOWTO point an <action> in struts.xml to a different <action>?

Tags: struts2, struts, action, redirecttoaction

Basically when the user goes to `example.com` I want to serve it the same content I would have, if it went to `example.com/news`. Below is the code snippet.

Current COnfig

```
  <action name="" class="action.public.news">
        <result>/jsp/labs/listLabs.jsp</result>
    </action>
<action name="news" class="action.public.news">
        <result>/jsp/labs/listLabs.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Desried COnfig

```
<action name="" class="action.public.news">
        Use Action Named "news" instead
    </action>

    <action name="news" class="action.public.news">
        <result>/jsp/labs/listLabs.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: Why do't you try with [urlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)?

Comment: @Nacho  we can achieve this in other way why to do extra work??

Comment: Well, a filter like this saves lots of time in the mid-long term

Comment: @Nacho OP is asking about executing an action not about changing the URL structure or SEO

Comment: For that reason i'm commenting, not posting an answer. Also researching on it will make no harm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand it right you want that when user hit the base domain `example.com` it should fetch the content of the action `news` one way to do this is.

create an empty file name welcome in your web-content folder.Add following entry to your web.xml

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>action2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>action2</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
         <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>    
         <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
         <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
         <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

replace your welcome list file in web.xml as

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>welcome</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and finally in your strus.xml do something like

```
<action name="welcome" class="action.public.news">
        <result>/jsp/labs/listLabs.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

what we are trying to do is that when we hit `example.com` instead of showing the welcome jsp file we are hitting the action and using its result

Answer (score 0):

Most people create a index.jsp page in the webapp folder containing this:

```
<% response.sendRedirect("index.action"); %>
```

This will redirect the visitor to the index.action when they arrive at your domain. Then, in struts.xml:

```
<action name="index" class="action.public.news">
   <result>/jsp/labs/listLabs.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Cheers,
Christian